# transitive dependency using GWT Plugin Eclipse

Tags: gwt, classpath, web-inf

I have Project A which is a GWT Project with RPC stuff. The Server part Depends on a Project B and that project (B) depends on some thirdparty ABC.jar's

When i Run the GWT project with Run/Debug the ClassPath doesn't contain the ABC'jars - only the compiled classes from Project A and B is in the WEB-INF/lib folder  and the GwtServlet.jar.. thingy.

Any help would be very welcome ..

ps: We are not using Maven and wont be using it in any near future ...

Answer (score 0):

put ABC.jar into the war/WEB-INF/lib folder

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects

I you cannot use Maven in your project for dependency resolution and don't want to manage them by hand Apache Ivy (+Ant) may be another option.